# Why does opening a kibana URL (with query) from macOS command line using `open` redirect to the 'unfilitered' landing screen?

Tags: bash, macos, elasticsearch, command-line, kibana

Ok, so here's the situation. I have a need at work to open a set of kibana URLs all at once, with different queries and filters. Each one is tedious to do, and when I have to do it, I need to do it 20+ times in a row. I decided I wanted to automate it with a simple bash script.

The script ends with

`open -a "Google Chrome" $the_kibana_url`

At first, I thought it was an issue with variable expansion and bash, so I stripped it down to just the `open` command, and a *single quoted* string literal of the url.

To be clear, this URL was taken directly from the chrome omnibar and pasted into the terminal.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" 'https://kibanalogs.redacted.tools/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(filters:!())&_a=(columns:!(namespace,pod,level,message),index:ee159830-some-index,interval:auto,query:(language:kuery,query:'level%20:%2050%20and%20pod%20:%20*canary*%20'),sort:!(!('@timestamp',desc)))'
```

I also took this URL, assigned it to `url` in the terminal, `echo`ed it out, and then repasted it successfully into the chrome omnibar.

So, when I use `open` to open this URL, it *looks* like it's going to work, but then it gets redirected back to the "blank" state: no query and no assigned display columns.

I've also run the command, and then copied the URL out of the omnibar before the redirect happens, assigned into another shell variable, and checked for string equality, and that checked out too, so it appears the `open` command is using an unaltered version of the URL it was supplied.

Finally, I've tried `open`ing other URLs that have suspicious special characters (`!`, `?`, `&`), and they have worked without issue, leading me to suspect there's something I don't know about kibana.

Oh, and p.s. Yes, the browser window is already logged in/authed, and it's on any required VPNs networks, so we can rule that out as well.

Anyone have any idea what to try next, or know what the issue is? I'm dying to automate this.

Recap:

**Goal && Expected Results:**
Open a kibana URL using from macOS terminal emulator prepopulated with a query and display columns.

**Actual Results:**
A new chrome tab is opened in the correct browser window with the URL *at first*, but it gets redirected to a "base" kibana URL, with no query or display columns.

**Errors:**

- none, the only symptom is the redirect thus far.

**What have I tried?**

- Shrinking the problem space down as small as possible, reducing the code to `open -a "Google Chrome" $single_quoted_url_shown_above`
- Reducing the URL modifications down to a single display column.
- Trying open URLs at other domains with potentially problematic characters like `!`, `?`, and `&`.

Edit: using kibana 7.5

Comment: Maybe just a quoting/escaping issue? cf. e.g. the end of your command: `open -a "Google Chrome" 'https://kibanalogs[…]sort:!(!('@timestamp',desc)))'`, where the `'` seems just broken.

Comment: It does, and you're totally right. When I store that URL to a shell variables like `url='https://kibanalogs[…]sort:!(!('@timestamp',desc)))'`, it doesn't break the string off at the first single quote before `@timestamp`. Instead, it removes the singles quotes that are wrapping `timestamp`.

That being said, I have a case for which that doesn't hold. I took my query and made a saved search, copied that URL and passed it to `open`, and *it worked*, even with `'@timestamp'` in the URL.